# how do I resolve the following error - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, string, int, operands, unsupportedoperation

I am getting the following error in my code. confirmed_India, recovered_India, deaths_India are list of table that includes a predefined dataset for corona cases .Code:

```
confirmed_India_ts = confirmed_df[confirmed_df['Country/Region'] == "India"]

confirmed_India_ts = confirmed_India_ts.drop(
['Lat','Long','Country/Region','Province/State'],axis=1).reset_index(drop=True).sum()

deaths_India_ts = deaths_df[deaths_df['Country/Region'] == "India"]

confirmed_India_ts = deaths_India_ts.drop(
['Lat','Long','Country/Region','Province/State'],axis=1).reset_index(drop=True).sum()

recovered_India_ts = recovered_df[recovered_df['Country/Region'] == "India"]

recovered_India_ts = deaths_India_ts.drop(
['Lat','Long','Country/Region','Province/State'],axis=1).reset_index(drop=True).sum()

active_India_ts = pd.Series(
    data = np.array(
            
[(x1 - x2 - x3) for (x1, x2, x3) in zip(
                confirmed_India_ts.values, deaths_India_ts.values, 

recovered_India_ts.values)
               
 ]
                
        ),
        index = confirmed_India_ts.index
)





error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-68268b5b4ce7> in <module>
 14         data = np.array(
 15                 [(x1 - x2 - x3) for (x1, x2, x3) in zip(
---> 16                     confirmed_India_ts.values, deaths_India_ts.values,      recovered_India_ts.values)
 17                     ]
 18 

 <ipython-input-54-68268b5b4ce7> in <listcomp>(.0)
 13 active_India_ts = pd.Series(
 14         data = np.array(
---> 15                 [(x1 - x2 - x3) for (x1, x2, x3) in zip(
 16                     confirmed_India_ts.values, deaths_India_ts.values, recovered_India_ts.values)
 17                     ]
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: What is the expected output for `(x1 - x2 - x3)` ?

Answer (score 0):

This error is suggesting that you are trying to subtract Integer type and String type. So I suggest you check your Data type of each of your x1,2,3 RIGHT before doing that (x1 - x2 - x3) Operation. Maybe you messed up one of the types during preprocessing. Eg.   x1 is Int type, but x2 is a string.

Please provide more info so I maybe able to help you.